# Notion Filter Active Tasks from Multiple Boards into One Board View for Monthly Planning

Tags: notion

I currently have a bunch of boards on Notion for different subjects or areas of stuff that I am tracking, kinda like an input queue for each for all my goals for the year. I plan on separating out these tasks into various months, with two sections for each of those, goals and stretch goals.

What I want is a joint-view board of all tasks for a given month or span of months across all of my separate tracking boards so I can get a high-level overview of everything I want to work on for easier monthly planning and tracking while being able to see all the total tasks I am taking on.

How would I do this? I am open also to other suggestions on how to structure these boards, but regardless I would like to know the answer if I were to keep approaching things this way.

Any help is appreciated.